# Laravel Homestead with multiple instances, one stating site unreachable

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am using Laravel Homestead on Windows 10 and my first application runs as 'Homestead' properly at site1.test.

Today I tried creating a second Homestead instance called 'homestead-for-wordpress' at site2.test but it returns an DNS error.

[image]

Here is my hosts file:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#       127.0.0.1       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
        192.168.10.10   site1.test
        192.168.10.11   site2.test
```

Here are my Homestead.yaml files:

Site1.test:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/Projects/site1
      to: /home/vagrant/site1.test

sites:
    - map: site1.test
      to: /home/vagrant/site1.test/public

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: true
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: true
    - webdriver: false
```

Site2.test (a WordPress site):

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.11"
name: "homestead-for-wordpress"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Documents/Projects/site2
      to: /home/vagrant/site2.test

sites:
    - map: site2.test
      to: /home/vagrant/site2.test

databases:
    - homestead

features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: yes
    - webdriver: false
```

Comment: Check in virtualbox if the second server is started properly and has set the right IP.

Comment: @Spencer Hill Did you try `ipconfig /flushdns`?

Comment: From the official docs:
If you are using Windows, you may need to enable hardware virtualization (VT-x). It can usually be enabled via your BIOS. If you are using Hyper-V on a UEFI system you may additionally need to disable Hyper-V in order to access VT-x.

Comment: VirtualBox is up and running. I did try flushing the DNS to no avail.

Comment: Thanks @Denis, in my BIOS I don't have an option to enable or disable Hardware Virtualization. But in Task Manager under the Performance tab it says Virtualization is enabled. As for Hyper-V it seems that's only available in Windows 10 Pro, but I am finding many tutorials of Windows 10 Home users running multiple instances of Homestead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Comment: Please include the VirtualBox configs  and processor specs, in your question.  "in my BIOS I don't have an option to enable or disable Hardware Virtualization" raises red flags.
The other question is are you trying to share any configuration between the VM's.
Is the second VM running?